# Powershell: tablet output to string of lines with one space

Tags: string, powershell, formatting, string-formatting

```
$allSoftwareObj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version | ft -HideTableHeaders | ft -Wrap -AutoSize -Property Name, Version

$allSoftware = Out-String -InputObject $allSoftwareObj 
echo $allSoftware
```

When I output this, I get a table structure. I don't want that.
How to get a new line per new output with only space between the Name and Version?

Wrong output now:

```
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types                           10.51.2500.0                                                                                  
SQL Server 2012 Client Tools                                    11.1.3000.0
```

Wanted output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types 10.51.2500.0
```

Or:

```
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (10.51.2500.0)
```

Comment: You're getting a table output from using `Format-Table`...

Comment: Might be worth a read: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/gramsey/archive/2011/01/25/win32-product-is-evil.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the whole line with this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |  % {"$($_.Name) ($($_.Version))"}
```

Comment: Oh you have additional format-tables in there...Hangon

Answer (score 1):

```
$allSoftwareObj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | %{ $_.Name + " " + $_.Version}
$allSoftwareObj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version | % { write-host "$($_.name) ($($_.version))" }
```